# Collapsing SQL Daily Status Table to a SCD

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with daily status that I would like to collapse into a SCD.

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id | cal_date   | status |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 2020-01-01 | A      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 2020-01-02 | B      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 2020-01-03 | B      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 2020-01-04 | B      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 2020-01-05 | C      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 2020-01-06 | C      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 2020-01-07 | B      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 2020-01-08 | B      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 2020-01-09 | C      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 2020-01-10 | C      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 2020-01-11 | B      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | etc        | B      |
+----+------------+--------+
| 1  | 2020-01-23 | B      |
+----+------------+--------+
```

collapses into

```
+----+--------+----------------------+---------------------------------------+
| id | status | effective_start_date | effective_end_date                    |
+----+--------+----------------------+---------------------------------------+
| 1  | A      | 2020-01-01           | 2020-01-01                            |
+----+--------+----------------------+---------------------------------------+
| 1  | B      | 2020-01-02           | 2020-01-04                            |
+----+--------+----------------------+---------------------------------------+
| 1  | C      | 2020-01-05           | 2020-01-06                            |
+----+--------+----------------------+---------------------------------------+
| 1  | B      | 2020-01-07           | 2020-01-08                            |
+----+--------+----------------------+---------------------------------------+
| 1  | C      | 2020-01-09           | 2020-01-10                            |
+----+--------+----------------------+---------------------------------------+
| 1  | B      | 2020-01-11           | NULL (or 2020-01-23 or 2099-12-31)    |
+----+--------+----------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

I think this is would be fairly straightforward if the statuses were ordinal/directional (A->B->C only), but this pattern (A->B->C->B->C->B) where any status can repeat is throwing me off.  Assuming no changes to status, this user will receive a B status record for every day going forward indefinitely. Is there a convenient way of doing this in BigQuery?

```
with data as (
  select 1 as id, cast('2020-01-01' as date) as cal_date, 'A' as status UNION ALL
  select 1, '2020-01-02','B' UNION ALL  select 1, '2020-01-03','B' UNION ALL  select 1, '2020-01-04','B' UNION ALL
  select 1, '2020-01-05','C' UNION ALL  select 1, '2020-01-06','C' UNION ALL  select 1, '2020-01-07','B' UNION ALL
  select 1, '2020-01-08','B' UNION ALL  select 1, '2020-01-09','C' UNION ALL  select 1, '2020-01-10','C' UNION ALL
  select 1, '2020-01-11','B' UNION ALL  select 1, '2020-01-12','B' UNION ALL  select 1, '2020-01-13','B' UNION ALL
  select 1, '2020-01-14','B' UNION ALL  select 1, '2020-01-15','B' UNION ALL  select 1, '2020-01-16','B' UNION ALL
  select 1, '2020-01-17','B' UNION ALL  select 1, '2020-01-18','B' UNION ALL  select 1, '2020-01-19','B' UNION ALL
  select 1, '2020-01-20','B' UNION ALL  select 1, '2020-01-21','B' UNION ALL  select 1, '2020-01-22','B' UNION ALL
  select 1, '2020-01-23','B' 
 )
 select * from data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, status, 
  MIN(cal_day) effective_start_date, 
  MAX(cal_day) effective_end_date
FROM (
  SELECT *, COUNTIF(new_group) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY cal_day) group_number
  FROM (
    SELECT *, status != LAG(status, 1, '') OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY cal_day) new_group
    FROM `project.dataset.data`
  )
)
GROUP BY id, status, group_number 
-- ORDER BY id, effective_start_date
```

If to apply to sample data from your question  - result is

```
Row id  status  effective_start_date    effective_end_date   
1   1   A       2020-01-01              2020-01-01   
2   1   B       2020-01-02              2020-01-04   
3   1   C       2020-01-05              2020-01-06   
4   1   B       2020-01-07              2020-01-08   
5   1   C       2020-01-09              2020-01-10   
6   1   B       2020-01-11              2020-01-23
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  Did not know about `COUNTIF` in BigQuery, but this is similar to how I would have solved it in Excel.